# How to compile gtkmm/gtk programs with Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, gtkmm

I've trying to compile a simple **gtkmm** program with Sublime Text, but the default C++ build system does not work as it doesn't point to the gtkmm library folder:

```
fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
```

However, after customizing `C++.sublime-build` and changing the *"cmd"* line to:

```
"cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`"],
```

I get the error:

```
g++: error: `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`: No such file or directory
```

Apparently ST2 is not running the `pkg-config` command prior to `g++`, which the back quotes usually do in the command shell. How do I force ST2 to do just that, in order to correctly include gtkmm folder?

Comment: you should install development package of `gtkmm-3.0`

Comment: I already have `gtkmm-3.0` installed, I can compile through the command line

Comment: Did you install development libraries? `apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-dev` for Ubuntu & Debian (note the -dev at the end... the regular gtkmm-3.0 is not enough)

Comment: what would be the equivalent to the development packages in archlinux? I already have `gtkmm` and `gtkmm3` installed.

Comment: @joaocandre development package contains header files not libraries,You find it  as `libgtkmm-3.0-dev` in debian-base system and as `libgtkmm-3.0-devel` in Redhat-base system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the "sublime-build" code some days ago on the stackoverflow, but I can't find it again, so I am attaching the .sublime-build file that works for me.

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++ -o ${file_base_name} ${file} `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0` && ./${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "shell":true
}
```

Comment: Using this build system, I get `gtkmm.h: No such file or directory` so the pkg-config command is still not being properly called.

Comment: It's nothing wrong with this code, it works properly on my Ubuntu and also on my archlinux machine. Look at the my comment to your question above.

Comment: found the error, I copy pasted your `.sublime-build` and I should have replaced `gtk+-3.0` with `gtkmm-3.0`